# is figsize real size of a Figure in matplotlib with jupyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib, I was looking into these 2 docs.
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html

I wrote the following lines of code to try to get an intuition of a figure.

```
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3),facecolor='black')
print(fig1.get_size_inches()*fig1.dpi)
fig2, axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(6,3),facecolor='black')
print(fig2.get_size_inches()*fig2.dpi)
```

The output confuses me. The whole area is one black figure? I save the image which is not 216 by 216 pixels.

Output
[image]

the width of `fig2` should be twice of `fig1` though the images are not.
any idea?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. And it'll all work as expected when using matplotlib in a python script. Yet here you are using IPython or Jupyter notebook. I suggest you read through the duplicate and if anything remains unclear, edit the question or ask a new one.